# Does Thunderbird automatically store emails so that they are accesible locally even after the account gets deleted

Tags: thunderbird

I have two IMAP accounts configured in Thunderbird (with some filters that move emails between remote folders, but without copying emails to local folders or similar). The emails are accessible when I am offline and I am wondering if they stay stored in Thunderbird even after my remote account gets deleted (university emails get deleted after graduation).

Comment: Yes, and if you install a plugin, you can export the emails as mbox files so that they can be read in other mail clients.

Comment: Yes all Thunderbirds mailboxes are stored in a hidden folder here:
/home/smihael/.thunderbird/some-number/....

Comment: So I don´t have to bother backuping mails now? I thought maybe if the account gets deleted (and hence emails get deleted on server too, this would result in deleted local copies after  IMAP syncing.